# How do I initialize the BabelJS library?

Tags: c#, reactjs, babeljs

I tried to use React with Babel JS ( http://reactjs.net/guides/es6.html ) 
The thing is that I cannot find any tutorial to guide through initializing it,

I have a string of a JavScript code within my C# application, for example:

```
string generatorStr ="function* generator() {
         foo();
         yield true;
         foo1();
         yield false;
    }";
```

I would like to transform it using the React.Babel library
I guess that it starts with:

```
React.Babel babel = new React.Babel(null, null, null, null, null);
string babelOutput = babel.Transform(generatorStr);
```

the thing is that i don't know what to place within the constructor(as you can see i have just used "null" but obviously it doesn't work that way)

Comment: The problem I have is I cannot initialize the React.Babel, if anyone knows how to do so I would appreciate it, as each argument has its own undocumented interface

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue- all I needed to do was to get the current Babel environment(and not to initialize it),using -

```
ReactEnvironment.Current.Babel
```